# Visual Studio View Parameters of Win32 API Function

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, winapi

I am trying to use Visual Studio to view the arguments passed to Windows API function `StartDocW` in `gdi32.dll` when printing from Notepad.exe.

I am using Visual Studio 2022 Community on Windows 11 x64.

I have successfully done the following:

- Start Notepad.exe
- Attach to Process (Debug -> Attach to Process)
- Add a function breakpoint `{,,Gdi32.dll}StartDocW` (Debug -> New Breakpoint -> Function Breakpoint). Note that VS displayed a warning: The following breakpoint cannot be set: .. The breakpoint failed to bind. However, the breakpoint appeared to work.
- Observe the breakpoint hit in the Call Stack window when printing from Notepad.

[image: Call Stack stopped on StartDocW()]

I have right-clicked and selected "Show Parameter Names", "Show Parameter Types", and "Show Parameter Values".

I am aware that `StartDocW` has two parameters:

```
int StartDocW(
  [in] HDC            hdc,
  [in] const DOCINFOW *lpdi
);
```

[StartDocW Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-startdocw)

I want to see what arguments are passed into the parameters. I can do so with another program: API Monitor [API Monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor) , but I sometimes work on machines where I am permitted to run Visual Studio but not API Monitor.

Here is an example of what API Monitor reports when hitting a breakpoint on `StartDocW`.

[image: API Monitor Parameters Window]

Comment: You should also be able to look at the registers window. Based on the offsets in the screenshot, I'm assuming x64, so the first two parameters will be passed in RCX and RDX.

Comment: Once you have determined the address of the `DOCINFOW` structure, you can [set a watch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/watch-and-quickwatch-windows) expression (`(DOCINFOW*)<address>`). Assuming debug symbols are loaded, you can now expand the watch in the debugger and look at the structure fields.

Comment: @joshpoley, Yes, I am running Windows x64. I confirm that RDX is a pointer to the DOCINFO structure by viewing the memory at the specified address.

Comment: @IInspectable, I tried adding a watch as you suggested. Visual Studio displayed `identifier "DOCINFOW" is undefined`. I also tried with `DOCINFO`, but VS displayed a similar message.

Comment: `DOCINFOW` is a typedef, you could try `_DOCINFOW*` or `struct _DOCINFOW*` in case the typedef is confusing the debugger.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I have tried `_DOCINFOW*` and `struct _DOCINFOW*`. Both produced "identifier is undefined". Is there an option I need to configure so that Visual Studio can find the struct definition?